# Dataframe of points to PostGIS

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, geopandas

I have a csv file with some info and coordinates and I want to create a table in PostGIS with that CSV file. This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
from datetime import datetime
#import psycopg2
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry, WKTElement
from sqlalchemy import *

ruta=('csv_file')
df= pd.read_csv(ruta,sep=';')
df['Tiempo'] = df['Fecha'].map(str)+ " "+ df['Hora']

now = datetime.utcnow()
tiempos=[]
registro=[]
datetime_str = df["Tiempo"]

for i in datetime_str:
    datetime_object = datetime.strptime(i,'%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    check = now - datetime_object
    check.total_seconds()
    if (check.total_seconds() > 300):
        registro.append(1)
    else:
        registro.append(0)
df['Ocurrencia']=registro

gdf=geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df.lng, df.lat))
```

this is the new geodataframe

[image]

```
#database connection
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/Rayos')
#conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='Rayos' user='postgres' host='localhost' 
#password='postgres'")

gdf.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='append', index=False, 
                     dtype={'geometry': Geometry('POINT', srid= 4326)})
```

this is the error:

```
#old error
ValueError: geometry (geometry(POINT,4326)) not a string
#new error
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Point'
```

I made some changes according to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325415/writing-geopandas-data-frame-to-postgis).What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is your table set up with the projection and spatial geometry set? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233209/copy-geometry-data-as-hexewkb-from-csv-to-table-in-postgis

Comment: Sorry - what is a CDV file? It seems that you don't have geometry in this table, just columns of lat/lon, etc. If that is the case, you don't need postgis to do the import, but you will need it to do the conversion of lat and lon columns to geometry. I would think that you need an existing table in the same schema as the CDV (sqlite?) table.

Comment: Maybe you can provide us a part of the file you want to import, as actually stated it is unclear what you expect and what is the incoming format

Comment: I recently update the post with new code lines and now with the new lines I´m getting a new error in the last part

Comment: if i read this : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html?highlight=to_sql  it could be a syntax problem because 'Geometry('POINT', srid= 4326)' should be a string

Comment: However, i don't really understand why you want to use geopandas to import long\lat to Postgres Postgis. You can do it directly for exemple like this : https://www.dataiku.com/learn/guide/other/geo/convert-coordinates-with-PostGIS.html

Comment: @Maximilienjaffrès I made some changes to the code and also i preffer doing with python since I don`t know how to do what you said automaticly in PostGIS

Comment: I mean, you can use python, connect to the database as you did, but instead of going throug geopandas to write your queries, with a bit of text management, regexp and some SQL, you would succeed to write them. But geopandas should do this job, that's right =) Concerning your last error, are you sure you have the right column, maybe try to convert it in text (Hex or WKB) before running the "to_sql" command

Comment: I did what you said in the comment from Sept 19, I wrote the SQL queries in python and i works pretty fine, I also tried the answer from @snowman2 and it works too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are probably looking for `geopandas-postgis` (https://github.com/awburgess/geopandas-postgis; https://pypi.org/project/geopandas-postgis/)

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

import geopandas_postgis

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres/localhost:test")
gdf.postgis.to_postgis(con=engine, table_name='table_name', if_exists='append', index=False, geometry='Point')
```

UPDATE: geopandas has a [to_postgis](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_postgis.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_postgis) method now.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("postgresql://myusername:mypassword@myhost:5432/mydatabase")  

gdf.to_postgis("my_table", engine)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested every combination I could think of and wasn't able to use `to_sql` when using `geopandas.points_from_xy`. The data frame contains shapely  `Point` instances that can't be translated.

So I completely dropped GeoPandas and instead of

```
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df.lng, df.lat))
```

I used

```
df['location'] = "POINT(" + df['lng'].astype(str) + " " + df['lat'].astype(str) + ")"
```

Then `to_sql` works as expected when using the `dtype`

```
df.to_sql('table_name', engine, dtype={'location': Geometry(geometry_type='POINT', srid=4326)})
```

Comment: This answer worked for me, except I had to add the SRID to df['location']